# MongoDB Mongoose PureAutoInc Plugin seems to auto-increment on update of Document as well . Any solution?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, auto-increment

I am using Nodejs , MongoDb 
I used Mongoose to handle DB operations .

For my Documents , I need an incrementing id . Hence I used PureAutoinc.
https://github.com/mylovecompany/mongoose-pureautoinc

It works fine as documented. I did something like -

```
pureautoinc.init(db);

    var schema = new Schema({
        email: String,
        text:  String
    });

    schema.plugin(pureautoinc.plugin, {
        model: 'Subscriber',
        field: 'recordNum'
    });

var Subscriber = db.model('Subscriber', schema);
```

The autoincrement works fine for me . But the problem happens when I try to update any of my Documents . The autoincremented id / ( recordNum in this case ) gets autoincremented even when I am just updating the record .

How do I solve this problem ?

Comment: A quick glance of the source code would suggest that's how it works.

Comment: @WiredPrairie -   Thanks for the comment . I looked into the code . I also found that this issue had been raised and fixed in some new commits . But those commits havent been integrated into the main package yet. https://github.com/mylovecompany/mongoose-pureautoinc/issues